# How to save a list of lists as csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, save

I'm trying to web scrape a list of players and save it as CSV.

This is the result I'm looking for: a list of the first x (4 players in this example) for y teams (2 teams in the example, a total of 8 players)

|  |
| --- |
| P. Gallese |
| Kyle Smith |
| R. Jansson |
| Rodrigo Schlegel |
| Sean Johnson |
| Malte Amundsen |
| T. Martins |
| A. Callens |

Here is the code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    
    html_text = requests.get('https://www.rotowire.com/soccer/lineups.php?league=MLS').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
    lineups = soup.find_all('div', class_='lineup is-soccer')
    j = range(2)
    selections = []
    for index1 in j:
        selections.append(lineups[index1])
    for selection in selections:
        home_squad = selection.find('ul', class_='lineup__list is-home')
        home_players = home_squad.find_all('li', class_='lineup__player')
        list_home = []
        for home_player in home_players:
            h_player_name = home_player.find('a').text
            list_home.append(h_player_name)
        start_11 = list(list_home[i] for i in range(4))
        df_h = pd.DataFrame(start_11)
        df_h.to_csv('home.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Unfortunately I'm able to save only the last occurrence of the inner loop, thus just the last 4 players. I'm stuck, since if I try to append inside the inner loop I get the letters of the names, or "out of range", if I go to the outermost loop I get only the last player in the last team.

What I'm missing? Thanks for the help

Comment: don't write it inside loop but after exiting loop. OR you have to write in `append mode`

Comment: shorter: `start_11 = list_home[0:4]` and `selections = lineups[0:2]` or even `for selection in lineups[0:2]:`

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17'}

top_4_players = []
r = requests.get('https://www.rotowire.com/soccer/lineups.php?league=MLS', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
players_lists = soup.select('ul.lineup__list.is-home')
for x in players_lists[:2]:
    players_list = x.select('li.lineup__player')[:4]
    for player_link in players_list:
        top_4_players.append(player_link.select_one('a').text)
df = pd.DataFrame(top_4_players, columns = ['Top 4 Players'])
df.to_csv('home.csv', index=False, header=False)
df
```

This returns (for only 2 home lineup lists):

```
Top 4 Players
0   Sean Johnson
1   Malte Amundsen
2   T. Martins
3   A. Callens
4   Q. Westberg
5   D. Criscito
6   S. O'Neill
7   L. MacNaughton
```

Comment: Thanks! Another different approach. Is there a difference if I don't use Mozilla?

Comment: No there isn't - that's just the header. You can put any valid browser user-agent there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar script, I changed it a bit for your, it ll show much more than just usernames, you can find out if the player has an injury, his position, name.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/soccer/lineups.php?league=MLS'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
data = {}
for place in ['is-home', 'is-visit']:
    for box in soup.find_all('div', class_='lineup__box')[:-1]:
        team = box.find('div', {'class': ['lineup__team', place]}).get_text(strip=True)
        visit_team = box.find('div', {'class': ['lineup__team', place]}).get_text(strip=True)
        players = []
        for player in box.find('ul', {'class': ['lineup__list', place]}).find_all('li', class_='lineup__player'):
            name = player.find('a').get_text(strip=True)
            pos = player.find('div', class_='lineup__pos').get_text(strip=True)
            link = player.find('a').get('href')
            injury = None
            if player.find('span', class_='lineup__inj'):
                injury = player.find('span', class_='lineup__inj').get_text(strip=True)
            players.append({'Name': name, 'Position': pos, 'Link': link, 'Injury': injury})
        data[team] = players
        
for team in data:
    print('Team:' + team)
    for player in data[team][:4]:
        print(player['Name'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Team:NYC
Sean Johnson
Malte Amundsen
T. Martins
A. Callens
Team:TOR
Q. Westberg
D. Criscito
S. O'Neill
L. MacNaughton
Team:ORL
P. Gallese
Kyle Smith
R. Jansson
Rodrigo Schlegel
Team:CLB
Eloy Room
J. Mensah
J. Williams
J. Anibaba
Team:CIN
R. Celentano
G. Cameron
T. Blackett
N. Hagglund
Team:DCU
Rafael Romo
Sami Guediri
B. Hines-Ike
S. Birnbaum
Team:SKC
J. Pulskamp
Logan Ndenbe
A. Fontas
N. Isimat-Mirin
Team:HOU
Steve Clark
A. Lundqvist
T. Hadebe
Tim Parker
Team:WHI
I. Boehmer
R. Veselinovic
T. Blackmon
J. Nerwinski
Team:SOU
Stefan Frei
Nouhou Tolo
X. Arreaga
Yeimar Gomez
Team:RSL
Zac MacMath
Andrew Brody
Justen Glad
M. Silva
Team:POR
Aljaz Ivacic
C. Bravo
L. Mabiala
D. Zuparic
Team:ATX
Brad Stuver
J. Gallagher
R. Gabrielsen
J. Cascante
Team:GAL
J. Bond
R. Edwards
S. Coulibaly
D. Williams
Team:LAF
J. Gaines
D. Musovski
B. Rodriguez
Erik Duenas
```

Full output:

```
Team:NYC
{'Name': 'Sean Johnson', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/sean-johnson-17054', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Malte Amundsen', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/malte-amundsen-34461', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'T. Martins', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/thiago-martins-24061', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'A. Callens', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/alexander-callens-23428', 'Injury': None}
Team:TOR
{'Name': 'Q. Westberg', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/quentin-westberg-27608', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'D. Criscito', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/domenico-criscito-16059', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': "S. O'Neill", 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/shane-oneill-18957', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'L. MacNaughton', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/lukas-macnaughton-36348', 'Injury': None}
Team:ORL
{'Name': 'P. Gallese', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/pedro-gallese-5303', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Kyle Smith', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/kyle-smith-27215', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'R. Jansson', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/robin-jansson-27664', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Rodrigo Schlegel', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/rodrigo-schlegel-30948', 'Injury': None}
Team:CLB
{'Name': 'Eloy Room', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/eloy-room-26699', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'J. Mensah', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/jonathan-mensah-15891', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'J. Williams', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/josh-williams-17090', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'J. Anibaba', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/jalil-anibaba-17048', 'Injury': None}
Team:CIN
{'Name': 'R. Celentano', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/roman-celentano-36502', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'G. Cameron', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/geoff-cameron-16320', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'T. Blackett', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/tyler-blackett-17942', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'N. Hagglund', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/nick-hagglund-18854', 'Injury': None}
Team:DCU
{'Name': 'Rafael Romo', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/rafael-romo-16116', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Sami Guediri', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/sami-guediri-34637', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'B. Hines-Ike', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/brendan-hines-ike-34544', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'S. Birnbaum', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/steve-birnbaum-18636', 'Injury': None}
Team:SKC
{'Name': 'J. Pulskamp', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/john-pulskamp-33317', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Logan Ndenbe', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/logan-ndenbe-36246', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'A. Fontas', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/andreu-fontas-20565', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'N. Isimat-Mirin', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/nicolas-isimat-mirin-19443', 'Injury': None}
Team:HOU
{'Name': 'Steve Clark', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/steve-clark-18721', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'A. Lundqvist', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/adam-lundqvist-25811', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'T. Hadebe', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/teenage-hadebe-31664', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Tim Parker', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/tim-parker-18932', 'Injury': None}
Team:WHI
{'Name': 'I. Boehmer', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/isaac-boehmer-33098', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'R. Veselinovic', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/ranko-veselinovic-30989', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'T. Blackmon', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/tristan-blackmon-25566', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'J. Nerwinski', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/jake-nerwinski-23510', 'Injury': None}
Team:SOU
{'Name': 'Stefan Frei', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/stefan-frei-18658', 'Injury': 'QUES'}
{'Name': 'Nouhou Tolo', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/nouhou-tolo-23430', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'X. Arreaga', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/xavier-arreaga-27919', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Yeimar Gomez', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/yeimar-gomez-30976', 'Injury': None}
Team:RSL
{'Name': 'Zac MacMath', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/zac-macmath-18844', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Andrew Brody', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/andrew-brody-34542', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'Justen Glad', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/justen-glad-18802', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'M. Silva', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/marcelo-silva-12977', 'Injury': None}
Team:POR
{'Name': 'Aljaz Ivacic', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/aljaz-ivacic-27224', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'C. Bravo', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/claudio-nicolas-bravo-34541', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'L. Mabiala', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/larrys-mabiala-24574', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'D. Zuparic', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/dario-zuparic-21718', 'Injury': None}
Team:ATX
{'Name': 'Brad Stuver', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/brad-stuver-18866', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'J. Gallagher', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/jon-gallagher-25490', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'R. Gabrielsen', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/ruben-gabrielsen-30690', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'J. Cascante', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/julio-cascante-25531', 'Injury': None}
Team:GAL
{'Name': 'J. Bond', 'Position': 'GK', 'Link': '/soccer/player/jonathan-bond-19111', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'R. Edwards', 'Position': 'DL', 'Link': '/soccer/player/raheem-edwards-21458', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'S. Coulibaly', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/sega-coulibaly-34663', 'Injury': None}
{'Name': 'D. Williams', 'Position': 'DC', 'Link': '/soccer/player/derrick-williams-31084', 'Injury': None}
Team:LAF
{'Name': 'J. Gaines', 'Position': 'D', 'Link': '/soccer/player/julian-gaines-35748', 'Injury': 'QUES'}
{'Name': 'D. Musovski', 'Position': 'F', 'Link': '/soccer/player/danny-musovski-30911', 'Injury': 'QUES'}
{'Name': 'B. Rodriguez', 'Position': 'F', 'Link': '/soccer/player/brian-rodriguez-29638', 'Injury': 'QUES'}
{'Name': 'Erik Duenas', 'Position': 'M/D', 'Link': '/soccer/player/erik-duenas-33112', 'Injury': 'OUT'}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution seems more pro to me, I'll study it to learn your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write inside loop but after all loops.

And you should append to list created before all loops

You should also use slices `[:4]` and `[:2]` instead of `range()` and `for`-loop

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

html_text = requests.get('https://www.rotowire.com/soccer/lineups.php?league=MLS').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
lineups = soup.find_all('div', class_='lineup is-soccer')

# --- before loop ---

all_results = []

# --- loop ---

for selection in lineups[:2]:  # <-- use directly slice `[:2]`
    home_squad = selection.find('ul', class_='lineup__list is-home')
    home_players = home_squad.find_all('li', class_='lineup__player')

    for home_player in home_players[:4]:  # <-- use directly slice `[:4]`
        h_player_name = home_player.find('a').text
        all_results.append(h_player_name)  # <-- append 

# --- after loop ---

df_h = pd.DataFrame(all_results)
df_h.to_csv('home.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

---

And if you want to write inside loop then you have to use `append mode` - `to_csv(..., mode="a")`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

html_text = requests.get('https://www.rotowire.com/soccer/lineups.php?league=MLS').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
lineups = soup.find_all('div', class_='lineup is-soccer')

# --- before loop ---

# --- loop ---

for selection in lineups[:2]:
    home_squad = selection.find('ul', class_='lineup__list is-home')
    home_players = home_squad.find_all('li', class_='lineup__player')
    
    partial_results = []
    
    for home_player in home_players[:4]:
        h_player_name = home_player.find('a').text
        partial_results.append(h_player_name)
        
    df_h = pd.DataFrame(partial_results)
    df_h.to_csv('home.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a')

# --- after loop ---
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your time to give a more visual explanation! I'll use slices from now on. Hopefully I'll learn to use the loops correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jul 22 13:16:32 2022

@author: 
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

html_text = requests.get("https://www.rotowire.com/soccer/lineups.php?league=MLS").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
lineups = soup.find_all("div", class_="lineup is-soccer")
# print(lineups)
j = range(2)
selections = []
list_home = []

count = 0
for index1 in j:
    selections.append(lineups[index1])
for selection in selections:

    home_squad = selection.find("ul", class_="lineup__list is-home")
    home_players = home_squad.find_all("li", class_="lineup__player")

    for home_player in home_players[0:4]:
        h_player_name = home_player.find("a").text
        print(h_player_name)
        list_home.append(h_player_name)

df_h = pd.DataFrame(list_home)
df_h.to_csv("home.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! That exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).